# Google Ads Data Transfer - MCC account - Can't find "AccountName"

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I'm working at an agency and I would like to get the Spend data for all of our accounts to be imported into BigQuery to make a budget overview dashboard.

I've set up a Data Transfer and I managed to join some tables in the SQL editor from doing some research and learning SQL along the way. The data I get seems to be good.

However, I can't seem to find "Account Name" anywhere in the tables/views, I only find "ExternalCustomerId" which matches the AccountId, but the Account Name would of course be much better.

I've found that in the "Account Performance Report" or "Campaign Criteria", the name should be available, but I don't have these reports in my Data Transfer, I get different tables (see screenshots).

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/account-performance-report

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-criteria-report

[screenshot: available campaign reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jlrl.png)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The account name should be available in the `p_Customer_xxx` table(s) of your export:

[image]